# Python bs4 sudden 'TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable'

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Why my code suddenly encounter an error after few success loop?

My code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import os

path =r'C:\Users\mrfau\Documents\python\stock_screener_001\crypto_project'
urls= pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path,r'all_coin_link.csv'))
urls_2 = ['https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/', 'https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/ethereum/', 'https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/solana/']

ranks = []
names = []
prices = []
count = 0

for url in urls['coin_link']:
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    count += 1
    print('Loop', count, f'started for {url}')
    rank = []
    name = []
    price = []
    for item in soup.find('div', class_ = 'sc-16r8icm-0 bILTHz'):
        item = item.text
        rank.append(item)
    ranks.append(rank)

    for ticker in soup.find('h2', class_ = 'sc-1q9q90x-0 jCInrl h1'):
        ticker = ticker.text
        name.append(ticker)
    names.append(name)

    for price_tag in soup.find('div', class_ = 'sc-16r8icm-0 kjciSH priceTitle'):
        price_tag = price_tag.text
        price.append(price_tag)
    prices.append(price)

df = pd.DataFrame(ranks)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(names)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(prices)
final_table = pd.concat([df, df2, df3], axis=1)
final_table.columns=['rank', 'type', 'watchlist', 'name', 'symbol', 'price', 'changes']

final_table.to_csv(os.path.join(path,r'summary.csv'))
```

The success output when I try using urls_2:

```
      rank  type                watchlist      name symbol       price changes
0  Rank #1  Coin  On 2,701,732 watchlists   Bitcoin    BTC  $64,166.71   0.37%
1  Rank #2  Coin  On 2,187,875 watchlists  Ethereum    ETH   $4,673.75   0.76%
2  Rank #5  Coin    On 890,655 watchlists    Solana    SOL     $229.95   1.41%
      rank  type                watchlist      name symbol       price changes
0  Rank #1  Coin  On 2,701,732 watchlists   Bitcoin    BTC  $64,166.71   0.37%
2  Rank #5  Coin    On 890,655 watchlists    Solana    SOL     $229.95   1.41%
```

When I tried to run the full list (7k URLs), the loop got an error at loop no. 76 and when I check the link is
https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/kucoin-token/

```
Loop 74 started for https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/compound/
Loop 75 started for https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/nexo/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\mrfau\Documents\python\stock_screener_001\crypto_project\get_watchlist.py", line 23, in <module>
    for item in soup.find('div', class_ = 'sc-16r8icm-0 bILTHz'):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Any idea why the sudden error after success? I checked the class it's all there.

I hope someone can help me. Thanks

Comment: Beautifulsoup has the unfortunate habit to return `None` if it does not find anything, forcing you to add an extra code to handle this if you want to iterate over the result.

Comment: Coinmarketcap has an API which you can use as well. It would likely yield more consistent results.

Comment: It *may* be that certain parts of the HTML are generated with JavaScript. Thus, if you use your browser's web inspector you may see the div with those class attributes but they're not actually there from BeautifulSoup's perspective. Try *selenium* or some other module that's JavaScript aware